# Global variable's value doesn't change after for Loop

Tags: java, variables, hadoop, for-loop, scope

I am developing a hadoop project. I want to find customers in a certain day and then write those with the max consumption in that day. In my reducer class, for some reason, the global variable *max* doesn't change it's value after a for loop.

**EDIT** I want to find the customers with max consumption in a certain day. I have managed to find the customers in the date I want, but I am facing a problem in my Reducer class. Here is the code:

**EDIT #2** I already know that the values(consumption) are Natural numbers. So in my output file I want to be only the customers, of a certain day, with max consumption.

**EDIT #3** My input file is consisted of many data. It has three columns; the customer's id, the timestamp (yyyy-mm-DD HH:mm:ss) and the consumption

**Driver class**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class alicanteDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long t_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long t_end;

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Alicante");
        job.setJarByClass(alicanteDriver.class);

        job.setMapperClass(alicanteMapperC.class);        

        //job.setCombinerClass(alicanteCombiner.class);

        job.setPartitionerClass(alicantePartitioner.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(2);

        job.setReducerClass(alicanteReducerC.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/alicante_1y.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/alicante_output"));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        t_end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println((t_end-t_start)/1000);
    }
 }
```

**Mapper class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class alicanteMapperC extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    String Customer = new String();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date t = new Date();
    IntWritable Consumption = new IntWritable();
    int counter = 0;

    // new vars
    int max = 0;

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Date d2 = null;
        try {
            d2 = ft.parse("2013-07-01 01:00:00");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (counter > 0) {

            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                Customer = itr.nextToken();
                try {
                    t = ft.parse(itr.nextToken());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Consumption.set(Integer.parseInt(itr.nextToken()));

                //sort out as many values as possible
                if(Consumption.get() > max) {
                    max = Consumption.get();
                }

                //find customers in a certain date
                if (t.compareTo(d2) == 0 && Consumption.get() == max) {
                    context.write(new Text(Customer), Consumption);
                }
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

**Reducer class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

public class alicanteReducerC extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int max = 0; //this var

        // declaration of Lists
        List<Text> l1 = new ArrayList<Text>();
        List<IntWritable> l2 = new ArrayList<IntWritable>();

        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            if (val.get() > max) {
                max = val.get();
            }
            l1.add(key);
            l2.add(val);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
            if (l2.get(i).get() == max) {
                context.write(key, new IntWritable(max));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Some values of the Input file**

```
C11FA586148,2013-07-01 01:00:00,3
C11FA586152,2015-09-01 15:22:22,3
C11FA586168,2015-02-01 15:22:22,1
C11FA586258,2013-07-01 01:00:00,5
C11FA586413,2013-07-01 01:00:00,5
C11UA487446,2013-09-01 15:22:22,3
C11UA487446,2013-07-01 01:00:00,3
C11FA586148,2013-07-01 01:00:00,4
```

**Output should be**

```
C11FA586258 5
C11FA586413 5
```

I have searched the forums for a couple of hours, and still can't find the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: `max = val.get();` is done inside an If. My guess is either values is empty and/or it contains no value over 0.

Comment: @alexbt It isn;t empty. It has numbers from 1-5 in it. The strange thing is that, in the output file I get the specific value for its key; meaning that the comparison "l2.get(i).get() == max" doesn't really do much.

Comment: So if we’re to help, I’m afraid you will need to do a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OleV.V.I hope my edit helps.

Comment: @CharisCh - it will be helpful if you just add 2-3 lines of sample input, and your expected output...

Comment: @RonakPatel Better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***here is the refactored code:*** you can pass/change specific value for date of consumption. In this case you don't need reducer. my first answer was to query max comsumption from input, and this answer is to query user provided consumption from input. 
  `setup` method will get user provided value for `mapper.maxConsumption.date` and pass them to `map` method. 
 `cleaup` method in reducer scans all max consumption customers and writes final max in input (i.e, 5 in this case) - see screen shot for detail execution log:

***run as:***

```
hadoop jar maxConsumption.jar -Dmapper.maxConsumption.date="2013-07-01 01:00:00" Data/input.txt output/maxConsupmtion5
```

---

```
#input:
C11FA586148,2013-07-01 01:00:00,3
C11FA586152,2015-09-01 15:22:22,3
C11FA586168,2015-02-01 15:22:22,1
C11FA586258,2013-07-01 01:00:00,5
C11FA586413,2013-07-01 01:00:00,5
C11UA487446,2013-09-01 15:22:22,3
C11UA487446,2013-07-01 01:00:00,3
C11FA586148,2013-07-01 01:00:00,4

#output:
C11FA586258 5
C11FA586413 5
```

---

```
public class maxConsumption  extends Configured implements Tool{

    public static class DataMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date dateInFile, filterDate;
        int lineno=0;
        private final static Text customer = new Text();
        private final static IntWritable consumption = new IntWritable();
        private final static Text maxConsumptionDate = new Text();

        public void setup(Context context) {
            Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
            maxConsumptionDate.set(config.get("mapper.maxConsumption.date"));
        }

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            try{
                lineno++;
                filterDate = ft.parse(maxConsumptionDate.toString());
                //map data from line/file
                String[] fields = value.toString().split(",");
                customer.set(fields[0].trim());
                dateInFile = ft.parse(fields[1].trim());
                consumption.set(Integer.parseInt(fields[2].trim()));

                if(dateInFile.equals(filterDate)) //only send to reducer if date filter matches....
                    context.write(new Text(customer), consumption);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Invaid Data at line: " + lineno + " Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }   
    }

    public  static class DataReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> maxConsumption = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int max=0;
            System.out.print("reducer received: " + key + " [ ");
            for(IntWritable value: values){
                System.out.print( value.get() + " ");
                if(value.get() > max)
                    max=value.get();
            }
            System.out.println( " ]");
            System.out.println(key.toString() + "    max is   " + max);
            maxConsumption.put(key.toString(), max);
        }

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int max=0;
            //first find the max from reducer
            for (String key : maxConsumption.keySet()){
                 System.out.println("cleaup customer : " + key.toString() + " consumption : " + maxConsumption.get(key) 
                         + " max: " + max); 
                if(maxConsumption.get(key) > max)
                    max=maxConsumption.get(key);
            }

            System.out.println("final max is: " + max);
            //write only the max value from map
            for (String key : maxConsumption.keySet()){
                if(maxConsumption.get(key) == max)
                    context.write(new Text(key), new IntWritable(maxConsumption.get(key)));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new maxConsumption(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: -Dmapper.maxConsumption.date=\"2013-07-01 01:00:00\" <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        Configuration conf = this.getConf();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "get-max-consumption");
        job.setJarByClass(maxConsumption.class);
        job.setMapperClass(DataMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(DataReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileSystem fs = null;
        Path dstFilePath = new Path(args[1]);
        try {
            fs = dstFilePath.getFileSystem(conf);
            if (fs.exists(dstFilePath))
                fs.delete(dstFilePath, true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    } 
}
```

[image: maxconsumption]

Comment: But with this way, I get way too much data. It still outputs values that are lower than the max consumption.

Comment: It can't.. I wondered in your driver class you may have missed reducer config... please post your driver class....

Comment: Check my driver class.

Comment: looks ok to me....you don't need combiner for this job, try running my version of code.. also remove partition class from driver....

Comment: For some reason it doesn't write anything. It just reads the file, but no output.

Comment: does filterdate exist in your input?

Comment: I changed it to a certain date I want the results to be, but still nothing.

Comment: not sure what could be problem then.... I added my full program with driver class, and tested with input in my answer....

Comment: Don't you need a while loop in the mapper class, in order to iterate the whole file?

Comment: no each input line is processed as one map method call...similarly...each key,values pair is processed as one reduce method call

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your time and I will keep trying to fix it.

Comment: Is it normal to get NullPointerExceptions in line #44 on your screenshot. (where the dates are being compared)?

Comment: yes...you may if you have empty line(s), or date is missing in you data....you can take that `if` block and put in same `try..catch`

Comment: see update...also forgot to increment `lineno` - updated

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. If you add more values in the input file, it mess up the whole thing. Check it yourself with my new input file.

Comment: The value of max keeps changing dynamically, so all values will be passed. For instance, in some time, max will be equal to 3 and all the consumptions with value 3 will be written to the output file until max changes.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and your effort, but I do need to find the max consumption. I thought I made it clear in my question.

Comment: no its not clear to me - I tried two of your requirements (1) find the max consumption for specific date (2) find the specific consumption for specific date ....add more specific details other thn this

Comment: it's in my 1st edit. I want to find the customers with max consumption in a certain day. First, I want to find the customers in a certain day, then I want to find the max consumption between those customers and finally write the customers of the certain day with the max consumption.

Comment: I tried two loops in reducer class, first one to find the max and the second to write the customers with the max consumption. but it didn't work.

Comment: doesn't my latest answer finds this? it is even more flexible for future, but for current requirement `mapper.maxConsumption` will be `5` and `mapper.maxConsumption.date` value will be changing

Comment: You set the max consumption as 5. It is supposed that we don't know the max consumption.

Comment: It's kinda "cheating" to set the max consumption at the beginning, don't you agree?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Probably all the values that go to your reducer are under 0. Try min value to identify if you variable change.

```
max = MIN_VALUE;
```

Based on what you say, the output should be only 0's (in this the max value in the reducers are 0) or no output (all values less than 0). Also, look this

```
context.write(key, new IntWritable());
```

it should be

```
context.write(key, new IntWritable(max));
```

EDIT: I just saw your Mapper class, it has a lot of problems. the following code is skiping the first element in every mapper.  why?

```
    if (counter > 0) {
```

I guess, that you are getting something like this right? "customer, 2013-07-01 01:00:00, 2,..." if that is the case and you are already filtering values, you should declare your max variable as local, not in the mapper scope, it would affect multiple customers.

There are a lot of questions around this.. you could explain your input for each mapper and what you want to do.

EDIT2: Based on your answer  I would try this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class AlicanteMapperC extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final int max = 5;
    private SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Date t = null;
        String[] line = value.toString().split(",");
        String customer = line[0];
        try {
            t = ft.parse(line[1]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new RuntimeException("something wrong with the date!" + line[1]);
        }
        Integer consumption = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);

        //find customers in a certain date
        if (t.compareTo(ft.parse("2013-07-01 01:00:00")) == 0 && consumption == max) {
            context.write(new Text(customer), new IntWritable(consumption));
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

and reducer pretty simple to emit 1 record per customer

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

public class AlicanteReducerC extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        //We already now that it is 5
         context.write(key, new IntWritable(5));
         //If you want something different, for example report customer with different values, you could iterate over the iterator like this 
         //for (IntWritable val : values) {
           // context.write(key, new IntWritable(val));
        //}      
    }
}
```

Comment: They are natural numbers, between 1-5.

Comment: changing your context.write(key, new IntWritable()); for context.write(key, new IntWritable(max));  work?

Comment: I couldn't find a better way to find the max consumption and the associated customers to it. That's why I chose double iteration.

Comment: context.write(key, new IntWritable(max)); just outputs all the values (including those being lower that the max). I really don't know why this happens.

Comment: probably is because you are emtting wrong values in the mapper and the reducer.. it would be useful if you provide a example of a couple of inputs and outputs (the current ones)

Comment: My input file is consisted of many data. It has three columns; the customer's id, the timestamp (yyyy-mm-DD HH:mm:ss) and the consumption